# How to create password encrypted zip file in python through AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zip

I am trying to create a password protected zip file through lambda that is running on python 3.9

I have tried using pyminizip and pyzipper but i encounter error for both libraries

For pyminizip, I keep encountering
`Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyminizip'`

For pyzipper, I keep encountering
`OSError: Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Hash._SHA1': Not found '_SHA1.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', Cannot load '_SHA1.abi3.so': /var/task/Cryptodome/Util/../Hash/_SHA1.abi3.so: invalid ELF header, Not found '_SHA1.so'`

For the libraries, I tried attaching it as layer or zip it together with my deployment package as zip and I still encounter the same error as above.

May I know any one successfully managed to use python in lambda to password encrypted as zip file?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your code, your os, etc. Did you upload the lib and the so file with your code?

Since I don't know much about what you did, I have created a simple lambda using ubuntu, pyminizip and python 3.7 to test it.

First of all, install pyminizip in your project's folder:

```
pip install pyminizip -t .
```

Note that you'll see a new folder, and a new so file:

[image: folder structure]

Note that you'll need to upload both to lambda.

Now, just write your code. I've created a simple script that reads a json I uploaded with my code, and save it zipped in lambda's tmp folder:

```
import os

import pyminizip


def lambda_handler(event, context):        
    print(os.path.exists("/tmp/test.zip"))
    pyminizip.compress("test.json", None, "/tmp/test.zip", "awesomepassword", 9)
    return "ok"
```

You can see the lambda's folder structure below:

[image]

And that's all. If you test your lambda, you'll see that it just works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond, I am currently running python 3.9 as my lambda runtimes, but I still encounter the same error. Do look at my answer, where i upload more info on my deployment package

Comment: I had the same setup in my deployment package, yet I am still encountering the same problem for python 3.9 
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFznu.png)
Code used was this  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6skg.png) , I have "import pyminizip" added at the top, completely clueless on what I am missing