# Lambda can't import the module pyminizip even though its already in the directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

So I have this similar problem with this person.
[How to create password encrypted zip file in python through AWS lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498991/how-to-create-password-encrypted-zip-file-in-python-through-aws-lambda)

We have the exact same problem but i already did everything from the answers in that thread but to no avail.

I have a lambda script that runs on python3.9 I need to compress the files in my s3 as a zip file that is password protected and i need to put it in another s3.
This is how it goes

```
import pyminizip
def zip_to_client():
    # reportTitles = os.listdir(tempDir)
    dateGenerated = datetime.now(tz=atz).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    pyminizip.compress("Daily_Booking_Report.csv", subfolder + str(dateGenerated) +'/'+str(id)+'/'
                , "/tmp/test.zip", "awesomepassword", 9)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename = '/tmp/test.zip', Bucket = bucket, Key = subfolder + 'test.zip', ExtraArgs={'Tagging':'archive=90days'})       
    print("SUCCESS: Transferred report into S3")
```

i'm not sure if it works but i can't debug it because lambda shows me the error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyminizip'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "0000111000",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I made sure that i put import pyminizip as well as pip installing it in the directory.
`pip install pyminizip -t .`

so far this is what the lambda directory looks like
https://ibb.co/ZGmLBbv

i've tried everything from putting it in a lambda layer to pip installing different versions from python 3.7 to 3.9

Answer (score 0):

This is a common case when you create a lambda layer and get import error. And this occurs when you don't have created python files in a defined directory like python/python38/site-packages...
or
second reason might be a dependency is missing. In that use use docker and follow steps from here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-packages-for-aws-lambda-layers/.