# Encrypt emails sent from AWS lambda using SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am working on a lambda function using SES to send emails having a CSV file as attachment. I have domain identity verified for all my organization team mates.

Any suggestions best way to encrypt data/email where users not require to use any decrypt key(as many may not have AWS access).
Or is there any way we can make sure only domain users can view this file, if its even forwarded to non domain user email attachment cannot be read.

Comment: Share your sensitive data using a protected link in the email content. Only users with access to the link password or behind a firewall can view it.

Comment: Never tried it, but Amazon WorkMail may suit your organization's needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than sending files via email, a better approach would be:

- Store the file in **Amazon S3**, as a private object (not publicly accessible)
- Have the AWS Lambda function generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides **time-limited access to private objects** in Amazon S3
- Include the URL in the e-mail
- Recipients can click the link to download the file, as long as it is within the expiry period

This is similar to providing a link to a file stored in DropBox. Only somebody with the link can access the object.

Comment: Thanks for posting a  solution , I have tried using s3 presigned url but my question is how to restrict users who are using this url. Right now I am able to click and download files from Pre-Signed URL whether I am in organization domain or not, so its not secure. Is there any way I make this pre-signed url only accessible within organization domain or folks having AD credentials?

Comment: You would verify the identity of the person _before_ giving them the pre-signed URL. Or, by trusting that the recipient of the email is permitted to access the object. If you want them to authenticate themselves, then you would need to write some software that asks for their AD credentials, verifies those credentials and only _then_ provides them with a time-limited URL.

Comment: Thanks both suggestions are long route involving other secure practices which takes me back to initial question - why to use pre signed url if i would be required to use additional services for security?

Comment: Your initial question was "best way to encrypt data/email where users not require to use any decrypt key". A pre-signed URL does not require a decryption key, and therefore meets that requirement. You also asked "Or is there any way we can make sure only domain users can view this file" and the answer is to first have domain users **authenticate** to prove their identity, and then provide a pre-signed URL. You also ask "why use pre signed url if i would be required to use additional services for security" and the answer is because that is a way to grant access to a private object in S3.

Comment: Put simply, if you want to grant somebody access to a private object in an Amazon s3 bucket, then they either need to authenticate with AWS credentials (but you say "many may not have AWS access"), or you use some external logic to determine whether they are entitled to access the object, and then provide a pre-signed URL to grant access to the object without requiring AWS credentials.

Comment: so why to use s3 here which you have suggested, i am needing to send csv files from lambda using SES in secure way. would encryption a better way or password protected file than s3 signed url ?

Comment: Your question asked for a way "where users not require to use any decrypt key", which is why I suggested using a pre-signed URL. Yes, an alternate method would be to send a password-protected file, but that would require that they know the password to decrypt it. The decision is yours.

Comment: any suggestion how can i send a password-protected file ? i tried using pyminizip and uploaded dependency but it didnt worked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310800/csv-file-password-protection-using-python-3-9?noredirect=1#comment131192261_74310800

Comment: i was able to resolve my issue i was facing even after following same steps as listed in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498991/how-to-create-password-encrypted-zip-file-in-python-through-aws-lambda . I have generated pyminizip library on linux OS and then  it worked fine.